# ReactJS not able to print nested values in rest api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is first time I am writing a React app and have create a sample app using create-react-app. I am calling a rest api using axios and it returns me json below which is nested. My component display the first level attributes but not nested one please help understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<Card type="inner" title="Social">
            {social.dataall.map((social1,i) => (
                <div key={i} class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Name: {social1.FullName}</h5>
                        
                        {social1.Member1.map(function (member11, j) { 
                        return <div key={j}> <h5>member11</h5></div>
                        
                        {member11.User2.map(function (usr2, k) { 
                        return <div key={k}> <h5>Type: {usr2.firstName}</h5></div>
                        })}
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
           ))}
</Card>
```

JSON to parse and display:

```
{"app":{"dataall":[{"FullName":"Payment","DisplayName":"Payment","Id":"3366d5e59","Member1":[{"User2":[{"userId":"331322934","firstName":"fName1","lastName":"lName1"}],"Role3":[{"roleName":"Business"}]},{"User2":[{"userId":"331322934","firstName":"fName","lastName":"lName"}],"Role3":[{"roleName":"Owner"}]}]}]}}
```

```
Output:
Name:  Payment
member11
member11
```

Not able to print the value for Type: {usr2.firstName}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `<div>` element here:

```
return <div key={j}> <h5>member11</h5></div>
//                                    ^^^^^^
```

That means the following code (`{member11.User2...`) is not part of the JSX element. It simply follows the `return` statement. Code after a returns statement is not executed:

```js
(function() {
  console.log("shown");
  return;
  console.log("not shown");
}());
```

You didn't explain how you want the UI to be structured but a simple solution would be to move the mapping inside the `<div>` element.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Name: {social1.FullName}</h5>
    {
      social1.Member1.map(function (member11, j) { 
        return (
          <div key={j}>
            <h5>member11</h5>
            {
              member11.User2.map(function (usr2, k) { 
                return <div key={k}> <h5>Type: {usr2.firstName}</h5></div>
              })
            }
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked able to get the values for Type now.

Comment: can you pls let me know how to enhance further loop to fetch roleName attribute nested down

Comment: basically on UI I want to show Type: firstName Last Name, Role: roleName